# What does file:file represent in this XSLT?

Tags: xml

I'm starting to use XSLT, and I don't understand this line:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="file:file/file:description" />
```

Why are there 3 `file`s ?
I know one of my tags in the XML file is named "file", but why prefixing "file:" ?

Here's the actual code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:file="http://phpdox.de/xml#"
   exclude-result-prefixes="#default file"
   >
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="file:file/file:description" />
    </body>
    </html>
<xsl:template match="file:description">
    <header>
        <p><xsl:value-of select="@compact" /></p>
        <p><xsl:value-of select="file:description" /></p>
    </header>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the source XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<file xmlns="http://phpdox.de/xml#">
  <class>
    <docblock>
      <description compact="foo bar"/>
  [...]
```

Comment: I doubt that the source file really looks like this, since its contents would not match the given namespace `http://phpdox.de/xml#`.

Comment: Yup you're right, I've cleaned a bit too much... I'll edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two of the three `file` tokens in `file:file/file:description` are **namespace names**. In XML and XSLT, `a:b` means "b in the a namespace". You can see the `xmlns` line explaining that `file` is a namespace once you know to look for it.

So the string means to find `file:description` (which may just look like `description` if everything in your document is in the `file` namespace) under `file:file`. Make sense?

Comment: Do you know any way to define a default namespace, because adding the "file:" prefix each time will be painful considering that I only use that namespace for now...

Comment: ask that as a separate question @FMaz008